# How to obtain coordinates of Sentinel-1 image

Tags: coordinates, satellite, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, sar

I’m a beginner in satellite image analysis. I want to know the lat/lon coordinates of some bursts of a sentinel-1 image. I looked at the file names of the downloaded zip, but couldn’t find any promising files(attached: file structure). Can someone teach me how I can obtain them?

Context: My purpose is to generate a coherence image and project to QGIS. I used SNAP following up to p12 of this tutorial(https://step.esa.int/docs/tutorials/S1TBX%20TOPSAR%20Interferometry%20with%20Sentinel-1%20Tutorial_v2.pdf). but the coordinates were somehow lost from the first step(importing and choosing bursts so as to produce a split file). not sure why but it apparently happens with other satellites(https://earthenable.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/how-to-export-sar-images-with-geocoding-in-esa-snap/).  I was able to produce the coherence without coordinates, so I'm thinking if I can get the coordinates from the Sentinel file, I can just add it to the GeoTIFF myself.

I also want to ask, is this idea wrong? Are the Sentinel coordinates different from the coherence image as it undergoes back geocoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the coordinates of the bursts using this tool: https://share.streamlit.io/pbrotoisworo/s1-tops-split-analyzer/main/app.py

But actually, this should not be necessary when you process data within SNAP. Stick to the BEAM DIMAP format and don't forget to apply Range Doppler Terrain Correction as a last step to have all S1 data geocoded precisely.

S1 data are not georeferences after splitting by default.